# Why is np.mean only printing one value and not a value for each row and column? Learning Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
numpy_list = []
length_list = 9
print("Please enter 9 numbers multiples of 2.")
for i in range(length_list):
    numpy_list.append(float(input("Enter that number!\n")))
numpy_list = np.array(numpy_list)
print(np.floor(numpy_list))
print("\n")

numpy_list2 = []
length_list2 = 9
print("Please enter 9 more numbers for a second matrix. Remember multiples of 2!\n")
for j in range(length_list2):
    numpy_list2.append(float(input("Enter that number NOWWW!\n")))
numpy_list2 = np.array(numpy_list2)
print(np.floor(numpy_list2))
print("\n")

print(numpy_list.reshape(3, 3))
print("\n")
print(numpy_list2.reshape(3, 3))
print("\n")

selection = 0
while selection != 5:

    selection = int(input("What would you like to do to the matrices?\n"
                  "1: Add\n"
                  "2: Subtract\n"
                  "3: Multiply\n"
                  "4: Element to element multiplication\n"
                  "5: To exit.\n"))

    if selection == 1:
        added = numpy_list + numpy_list2
        print(added.reshape(3,3))
        print("This is the transpose: \n", np.transpose(added).reshape(3, 3))
        added_col_ave = np.mean(added, axis=0)
        print("The average of the columns is:", added_col_ave)
        added_row_ave = np.mean(added, axis=1)
        print("The average of the rows is:", added_row_ave)
```

Trying to get the mean to print out a mean value for each row and column but I am only getting one. Reading on it now, but I am not sure where my problem is. I am backtracking, looking to see if I missed a step.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is 9 elements, just use

```
numpy_list.reshape(3, 3)
```

also note that by convention you can abbreviate `numpy` using `import numpy as np` and then you can call `np.array`, `np.floor`, etc...

Comment: Not sure why I got banned from asking questions so I cant edit, but trying to calculate the mean now, and its only printing one value its not printing the value for each row and column